# What is 'google_cloud_storage_conn_id'?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm using Airflow's *GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator*. But I don't understand what is *google_cloud_storage_conn_id* and where I can find it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow allows you to store `Connection` objects in its database via the web console. These connections can be referenced within DAG's so that you're not hard-coding credentials.

To use the `GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator`, you'll first want to store the credentials to your Google Cloud Storage setup in [Airflow's Connections](http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/configuration.html#connections) interface.

Then, to use the `GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator` within a DAG, you'll just need to pass the Operator the `google_cloud_storage_conn_id`:

```
some_task = GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator(
    ...
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='my_google_cloud_storage',
    ...
)
```